# Weird arduino bug, using microphone and relay

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I made a clap light switch to control my room lights and ground LEDs, and it works perfectly but when ever I have both the LEDs and the lights on it kinda stops working.
I use two claps for the lights and three for the LEDs.
Does anyone know what could be wrong? here is my code.

```
/* DEFINE PINS */
const int buzzer = 2;
const int micPin = 0;
const int relayLED = 9;
const int relayLights = 8;

const int sampleWindow = 50;
const int N = 50;

unsigned int sample;

boolean lights = false; //lighs on or off
boolean leds = false; //leds on or off

double soundArray[N]; //array to check claps

int i = 0;
int clapsCount = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(relayLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relayLights, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(relayLights, HIGH);
}


void loop() {
  /* gets 50 constant sound sample and resets */
  if (i<N) {
    soundArray[i] = getVolts(); 
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  if (i == N-1) {
    clapsCount = clapCount(soundArray);
  }

  /* if 2 claps detected do this */
  if (clapsCount == 2) {
    if (lights == false) {
      turnOnLights();
      lights = true;
    } else {
      turnOffLights();
      lights = false;
    }
    playSound();
    clapsCount = 0;
  }

  /* if 3 claps detected do this */
  if (clapsCount == 3) {
    if (leds == false) {
      turnOnLeds();
      leds = true;
    } else {
      turnOffLeds();
      leds = false;
    }
    playSound();
    clapsCount = 0;
  }
}

int clapCount(double soundArray[]) {
  int claps = 0;
  for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
    if (soundArray[j] > 3.0 && soundArray[j] < 3.5) {
      claps++;
    }
  }
  return claps;
}

void turnOnLights() {
  digitalWrite(relayLights, LOW);
}

void turnOffLights() {
  digitalWrite(relayLights, HIGH);
}

void turnOnLeds() {
  digitalWrite(relayLED, LOW);
}

void turnOffLeds() {
  digitalWrite(relayLED, HIGH);
}

/* gets mic volts */
double getVolts() {
  unsigned long startMillis= millis();  // Start of sample window
  unsigned int peakToPeak = 0;   // peak-to-peak level
  unsigned int signalMax = 0;
  unsigned int signalMin = 1024;
  // collect data for 50 mS
  while (millis() - startMillis < sampleWindow)
  {
    sample = analogRead(micPin);
    if (sample < 1024) {
       if (sample > signalMax) {
          signalMax = sample;  // save just the max levels
       }
       else if (sample < signalMin) {
          signalMin = sample;  // save just the min levels
       }
    }
  }
  peakToPeak = signalMax - signalMin;  // max - min = peak-peak amplitude
  double volts = (peakToPeak * 5.0) / 1024;  // convert to volts
  return volts;
}

void playSound() {
  tone(buzzer, 1000);
  delay(100);
  tone(buzzer, 500);
  delay(100);
  noTone(buzzer);
}
```

**Edit:**
When I do both two claps and three claps, both lights turn on and no matter how many times I clap none of them turn back off.

**Edit 2:**
Components I am using are, a simple buzzer, and microphone called MAX4466 and a 5v relay with two outputs.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what you mean by "kinda stops working".

Comment: @per1234 edited now, sorry about that.

Comment: We need to know what these devices are and how they are connected. The code listing has some issues, but we can't do a good answer without the hardware info. Like, are you using an actual microphone, condenser, piezo, what? I suspect your method of identifying a clap isn't working how you think it is.

Comment: I read your code and looks well written at first sight. Not having the hardware, I can elaborate on the physical aspects of your problems. It can be how your are sampling or counting. Put some Serial.print in `getVolts` and `clapCount` to test that they detect and count correctly. You can also use an hand filled `soundArray` to check the logic.

Comment: Apologies again, I edited it one more time with the other information.

Comment: This scheme of clap counting does not seem sufficiently though through to work at all - first, you evaluate in a buffer and then throw everything away, so you'd have to luck out and get all your claps in a buffer, and not some in an old one that gets throw away and the rest in the next.  But more importantly, you don't seem to ever implement anything that looks for a sharp sound **and then a gap**.  You basically need to start over with a plausible algorithm - you need to count sounds with intervening gaps, and then act only when theres been a long enough gap to mean no more will follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked through your code and can't see anything obvious that is causing the problem, so I have refactored it a bit in the hope that the problem becomes more obvious.

```
/* DEFINE PINS */
const int PinBuzzer = 2;
const int PinMic = 0;
const int PinRelayLED = 9;
const int PinRelayLights = 8;

const int sampleWindow = 50;
const int MaxSamples = 50;

// Simple enumeration to clarify which state is on and off.
enum EOnOff { Off, On };
EOnOff lights = Off; //lights on or off
EOnOff leds = Off; //leds on or off

double soundArray[MaxSamples]; //array to check claps


void setup() 
{
    pinMode(PinRelayLED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PinRelayLights, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(PinRelayLED, ConvertOnOff(leds));
    digitalWrite(PinRelayLights, ConvertOnOff(lights));
}


void loop() 
{
    for (int sample = 0; sample < MaxSamples; ++sample)
    {   // Get the samples
        soundArray[sample] = getVolts();
    }
    switch (clapCount())
    {   // Analyse the samples
    case 2:
        lights = ChangeRelay(lights, PinRelayLights);
        playSound();
        break;
    case 3:
        leds = ChangeRelay(leds, PinRelayLEDs);
        playSound();
        break;
    }
}

/// Count the number of 'claps' in the sample data
int clapCount(/*clap array is global*/) 
{
    int claps = 0;
    for (int sample = 0; sample < MaxSample; ++sample) 
    {
        if (soundArray[sample] > 3.0 && soundArray[sample] < 3.5) /* Why 3.5?? */
        {
            ++claps;
        }
    }
    return claps;
}

/// Convert an EOnOff value to a HIGH or LOW value.
// OFF = HIGH
int ConvertOnOff(const EOnOff& state)
{
    return state == Off ? HIGH : LOW;
}

/// Change a relay to the given state.
/// Return the new state.
EOnOff ControlRelay(const EOnOff& state, const int& relayPin)
{
    EOnOff result = state == On ? Off : On;
    digitalWrite(relayPin, ConvertOnOff (result));
    return result;
}


/* gets mic volts */
double getVolts() 
{
    const unsigned long startMillis = millis();  // Start of sample window
    unsigned int signalMax = 0;
    unsigned int signalMin = 1024;

    unsigned int sample;
    // collect data for 50 mS
    while (millis() - startMillis < sampleWindow)
    {
        sample = analogRead(PinMic);
        if (sample < 1024)                  // ?? Should this be 1024 or signalMin?
        {
            if (sample > signalMax) 
            {
                signalMax = sample;  // save just the max levels
            }
            else if (sample < signalMin) 
            {
                signalMin = sample;  // save just the min levels
            }
        }
    }
    const unsigned int peakToPeak = signalMax - signalMin;  // max - min = peak-peak amplitude
    const double volts = (peakToPeak * 5.0) / 1024.0;       // convert to volts
    return volts;
}

void playSound() 
{
    tone(buzzer, 1000);
    delay(100);
    tone(buzzer, 500);
    delay(100);
    noTone(buzzer);
}
```

What I have tried to do is to reduce the number of lines of code.  If there are less lines then there should be less bugs :)

You used a bool to record the on off state, I changed that to an enumeration because that adds a bit of clarity, and when working with mains voltages I like things being clear.

I changed your while loop into a for loop, I think it looks cleaner.  This was also the reason I changed your if statements into a switch statement.

The guts of the if statements have been removed and placed in a function `ChangeRelay()`, it returns the new state of leds or lights.  I could have gone with a reference to make `state` an in out parameter, but decided a return was simpler.

`ClapCount()` and `GetVolts()` are relatively unchanged apart from a bit of const'ing of variables to make things easier to read.  Also you might have noticed I, j and N have all been removed, because single letter variable names are my nemesis, who knows what `q` means and why `r` and `t` are being added to it to make `z`?

ControlRelay lets you route all you relay switching through one function, if there was a copy and paste bug in your code (which I don't think there was) then they will either all work or not work now.

There is a big difference between "my" code and yours, you won't be able to switch both on at the same time because the switch statement won't let you.  So in a way you problem is solved.  If you really wanted to you could add:

```
case 5: 
    lights = ChangeRelay(lights, PinRelayLights);
    leds = ChangeRelay(leds, PinRelayLEDs);
    playSound();
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you for making the code better!
I tried it and it works just like mine, but the bug still happens, I am not sure if  it is a limitation of the relay, if both lights are on it does not turn off no matter what.
And yeah I know the single letter variables are bad, I normally use only single variables like i, j, k for the for loops, but since I was just testing I got some weird ones with single letter too.

Comment: I tried using the serial read to type 2 or 3 as simulation of the claps and it works perfectly fine, got both on, turn off each at a time all perfect, but when ever it is claps it doesnt seem to work, maybe my algorithm to get the claps is bad.

Comment: @Matthew - In `getVolts` the `else if` should be just an `if`.  Otherwise you need two samples to adjust the max and min to the correct values.